# mfmailcomposeviewcontroller code does not work

Tags: iphone, sendmail

I had a tab view controller within which I used to call the code below and it was working fine. I removed the tab and made it a simple navigation controller, but then the same code stopped working. The mail view does not show up. The button action does nothing.
What could be wrong with below code

```
 if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"]];
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    [mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"test@test.com"]];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
    [mailViewController release];}
```

Comment: does it give you any errors?, do you still have MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate declared?

Comment: It does not give me any errors. I have not declared the delegate, just imported #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

Comment: Set a breakpoint to check if your method gets called. When stepping through it in the debugger, see if you don't have nil values where you would expect otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments above, I'm pretty sure that is your reason. You can't just import the header files to get the MFMailCompose to work. You have to implement the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate and the methods that go along with that for it to present the mail view correctly.

Here is a link to a nice tutorial that should help you out getting the methods configured correctly.

[In-App Email Tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email/)

Comment: thanks, but I have implemented the delegate methods, I realise.